# Kotlin dataStore boolean value in Jetpack Compose switch type missmatch

Tags: android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-jetpack-datastore

Im trying to store the boolean of the switch in kotlin dataStore and then set the switch value from the dataStore on change but i get a type mismatch:

[Error from android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PNFj.png)

this is my settings page:

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Settings(navController: NavHostController, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    //data
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val dataStore = StoreGruSwitch(context)
    val savedGru = dataStore.getGruSwitch.collectAsState(initial = "")
    //Variables

    Scaffold(
        //Header
        topBar= {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(text = "Settings")
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        navController.navigate("Start") {
                            popUpTo("Start") { inclusive = true }
                        }
                    }) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "Back arrow")
                    }
                },
            )
        },
        //mer

    ) { contentPadding ->
        //Content
        Column(modifier.padding(contentPadding)){
            //Switches
            Switch(checked = savedGru.value, onCheckedChange = { scope.launch { dataStore.saveGruSwitch(savedGru.value) } })
        }
    }
}
```

This is where i store the data:

```
class StoreGruSwitch(private val context: Context) {

    //To make sure there is one instance
    companion object{
        private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "GRU")
        val GRU_Switch = booleanPreferencesKey("gru_switch")
    }

    //Get variable
    val getGruSwitch: Flow<Any> = context.dataStore.data
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[GRU_Switch] ?: ""
        }

    //Save variable
    suspend fun saveGruSwitch(name: Boolean){
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[GRU_Switch] = name
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried searching around without finding anything to help me specific case.

Comment: You are sending type Any white fetching value using getGruSwitch. so just make sure you return boolean value from getGruSwitch